# Looking for C++ datawarehousing for time series data

Tags: c++, database, time-series, data-warehouse

I need a C++ library that can store and retrieve time series on demand to stream to client front-ends.  I will be storing each component as structure of arrays format.  I am currently using MySQL for correctness, but the DB access is starting to get ridiculously slow.  I am trying to migrate away from this.  Intuitively I can build such a library but it is not my business goal and will take quite a bit of implementation to get working.  I am looking for an existing solution that can meet the following requirements:

- O(1) lookup scheme
- Excellent compression, each component is separated, so there should be plenty of redundancy that can be removed
- Scalable to terabytes
- (optional: Audit tracking)

Most important: Transactional support.  There is going to be BIG data, and I can't have the possibility of a bad run corrupt an entire dataset which will create an unnecessary burden for backups and downtime during restores.

Comment: IF there isn't a lib, I'd be willing to put a project like this on some open-source repository, if anyone is interested.  I'd contribute but I don't have time to write the whole thing myself currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also checkout TempoDB: http://tempo-db.com  I'm a co-founder, and we built the service to solve this problem.  We don't have a C++ client yet, but could work with you to develop one.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at OpenTSDB it's been develop at StumbleUpon by Benoit Sigoure:
http://opentsdb.net/

Comment: Hadoop / HBase seems to be the best solution for the OP, if a MPP data warehousing system such as Netezza, Teradata or Vertica is cost-prohibitive.

Answer (score 0):

[TeaFiles](http://www.discretelogics.com/TeaFiles) provide simple and efficient time series storage in flat files, enriched with item metadata and description. They might be a building block of the system you aim for. Currently free open source libraries exist for [C++ (github.com/discretelogics/TeaFiles)](http://github.com/discretelogics/TeaFiles), C# and Python.

I am a founder of discretelogics and we coined this file format to overcome litations flat file time series storage while preserving its unrivaled speed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/).  It has a quick lookup scheme, has C, C++, Python interfaces.  Has compression.  Can get pretty big.  Maintains metadata.  Doesn't do auditing.  You'll need a wrapper to handle multi-user capability.